# Count item in sharepoint list' view

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, list-view

I have a lot of list views.

Each view is displayed having group by name such as pending, working, complete ,......

I need to count each item inside group.

I need camel query in c#  to count each group have once i pass parameter(siteurl,listname,viewname)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code, Add `Microsoft.SharePoint` and `Microsoft.SharePoint.Security` Namespaces.

```
    public static int GetItemCount(string SiteUrl, string listName, string viewName)
        {
            int count = 0;
            try
            {
                SPListItemCollection items = null;
                SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
                {
                    using (SPSite oSite = new SPSite(SiteUrl))
                    {
                        using (SPWeb oWeb = oSite.OpenWeb())
                        {
                            SPList list = oWeb.Lists.TryGetList(listName);
                            if (list == null)
                                throw new Exception(string.Format("List with List Name: {0} not found at url {1}", listName, SiteUrl));
                            SPView view = list.Views[viewName];
                            SPQuery ViewQuery = new SPQuery(view);
                            ViewQuery.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='ID'/>";   
ViewQuery.RowLimit = 0;
                            if (view == null)
                                throw new Exception(string.Format("View with View Name: {0} not found in List {1}", viewName, listName));
                            items = list.GetItems(ViewQuery);
                            if (items != null)
                                count = items.Count;
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Logs your Exception
            }

            return count;
        }
```

Comment: This can be optimized since all we need is count. Use the view's filter, but don't fetch all columns, just fetching ID is enough.

Comment: @Prakash-CrowCanyon Thanks, I have updated the Optimized Code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to get count of items for particular list view

```
using (SPSite oSiteCollection = new SPSite(strUrl))
{
    using(SPWeb oWebsite = oSiteCollection.AllWebs["Website_Name"])
    {
     SPList oList = oWebsite.Lists["List_Name"];
     string viewGUID = list.Views["View_Name"].ID.ToString("B").ToUpper();
    SPQuery query = new SPQuery() { Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Title' /></OrderBy>" };
     SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query,viewGUID);
     int count = items.Count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do we need OrderBy here? Will it alter count in any way?